# Is there a reliable way to avoid permission denied errors when installing Ruby gems with native extensions on Windows Subsystem for Linux?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm hoping that WSL2 solves these problems and makes this question obsolete in the next 6 months or so, but in the meantime, I don't feel comfortable running bleeding edge or other preview releases of Windows on my primary laptop.

Sometimes, when I'm installing Ruby gems (`bundle install` or `bundle install --path=vendor/bundle`) inside of WSL, I get `Permission denied` errors when installing a gem with a native extension.

The most recent incarnation of this error was this:

```
Permission denied @ rb_file_s_rename - (./.gem.20191006-12131-11th7ub/byebug, /home/thomasowens/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.6.0-static/byebug-11.0.1/byebug)
```

To resolve it, I simply deleted `/home/thomasowens/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.6.0-static/byebug-11.0.1/byebug`, reran the bundle command, and it succeeded. Sometimes, I need to do this multiple times, but it usually works.

In the end, I can get all of the gems installed properly, but it's hard when setting up a new project and there are many gems with native extensions. Same when I'm introducing a new gem or updating a gem that causes the native dependencies to need to be updated.

I haven't found much about this issue, but I'm wondering if there is something that I can do to alleviate the pain of needing to run `bundle install` multiple times to get a project set up and running under WSL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem that I'm experiencing may be related to Visual Studio Code's file watching. It is reflected in two GitHub issues against WSL - [1956](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1956) and [3395](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/3395). Visual Studio Code has `remote.WSL.fileWatcher.polling`, which can be enabled which works around this issue. However, [the documentation states that there is a performance impact for large workspaces](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl#_i-see-eaccess-permission-denied-error-trying-to-rename-a-folder-in-the-open-workspace) and it may be necessary to also adjust the `remote.WSL.fileWatcher.pollingInterval` setting. WSL2 will resolve these issues.

Since enabling this flag, I haven't seen the error while working with VS Code running.

---

Now that WSL2 is out, I was able to disable this flag and the issue has not reappeared. It appears that if you can upgrade to WSL2, that may be a preferred solution. However, for anyone who hasn't yet upgraded or can't upgrade, toggling the `remote.WSL.fileWatcher.polling` and `remote.WSL.fileWatcher.pollingInterval` should be good.