# Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. Keep getting this message when running bundler install in VScode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, visual-studio-code, rubygems, bundler

I am trying to run a bundler install on vscode for windows, but every time I do, I keep getting the same message:

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.......
Resolving dependencies...
Using bundler 2.1.4
Fetching byebug 11.1.3
Installing byebug 11.1.3 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /home/chadcunn/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/byebug-11.1.3/ext/byebug
/home/chadcunn/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/bin/ruby -I /home/chadcunn/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0 -r ./siteconf20200718-7409-qq2a6i.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: /home/chadcunn/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/byebug-11.1.3/ext/byebug
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /home/chadcunn/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/byebug-11.1.3/ext/byebug
make "DESTDIR="
compiling breakpoint.c
compiling byebug.c
compiling context.c
compiling locker.c
compiling threads.c
linking shared-object byebug/byebug.so

current directory: /home/chadcunn/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/byebug-11.1.3/ext/byebug
make "DESTDIR=" install
/usr/bin/install -c -m 0755 byebug.so ./.gem.20200718-7409-z7mdim/byebug

Permission denied @ rb_file_s_rename - (./.gem.20200718-7409-z7mdim/byebug,
/home/chadcunn/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.7.0/byebug-11.1.3/byebug)

Gem files will remain installed in /home/chadcunn/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/byebug-11.1.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/chadcunn/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.7.0/byebug-11.1.3/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing byebug (11.1.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install byebug -v '11.1.3' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  byebug
```

And then when I try to see if gem install byebug succeeds i get this response:

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing byebug:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /home/chadcunn/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/byebug-11.1.3/ext/byebug
/home/chadcunn/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/bin/ruby -I /home/chadcunn/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0 -r ./siteconf20200718-7520-jpov6j.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: /home/chadcunn/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/byebug-11.1.3/ext/byebug
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /home/chadcunn/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/byebug-11.1.3/ext/byebug
make "DESTDIR="
compiling breakpoint.c
compiling byebug.c
compiling context.c
compiling locker.c
compiling threads.c
linking shared-object byebug/byebug.so

current directory: /home/chadcunn/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/byebug-11.1.3/ext/byebug
make "DESTDIR=" install
/usr/bin/install -c -m 0755 byebug.so ./.gem.20200718-7520-b4jxqm/byebug

Permission denied @ rb_file_s_rename - (./.gem.20200718-7520-b4jxqm/byebug, /home/chadcunn/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.7.0/byebug-11.1.3/byebug)

Gem files will remain installed in /home/chadcunn/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/byebug-11.1.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/chadcunn/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.7.0/byebug-11.1.3/gem_make.out
```

I am not very experienced with coding or computers, I am actually now just trying to learn how to work within these programs, but I have no clue how to fix this or what to do.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58261192/3784008

Comment: Please don't just add 'Solved' to the question title. Instead, please [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) that was most helpful to you.

Comment: Holger, none of the answers were helpful in my situation, I ended up removing everything and reinstalling Ubuntu and VScode

Answer (score 12):

Your system is missing native packages to compile byebug etc. You need to install this and try again. e.g

```sh
apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential
```

Answer (score 5):

Your system might be missing some ruby dependencies. The way I fixed this error on my Ubuntu based system was installing the `ruby-dev` package like this:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install ruby-dev
```

I am not so sure about window's systems, but I think problem is the same: missing dependencies. This link might be useful if you need more help: https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/installation/

Answer (score 2):

my problem lies in rbenv.
i fixed it by running: brew reinstall ruby-build
or: brew install rbenv ruby-build

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that `gem install byebug -v '11.1.3' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

So run `gem install byebug -v '11.1.3'` if the problem persists, try `gem install byebug` without specifying a version. Doing so, gem will search for the newest one.

However, if the problem persists, your ruby **version 2.7.1** may not have support for this byebug version yet. On this case, try a stable ruby version, for now 2.6.5, 2.6.6, that is, all 2.6.x are stables at this moment.

After you succeed well running `gem install byebug`, run `bundle install` againg.

What helps me a lot with ruby and rails was taking a look on the [official ruby web page](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/). On there you'll see many links to how to use the appropriated ruby version and rails versions according to your Operation System.

These things are not shown to much on tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

I solved by using below comments

> sudo curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby

Close & Reopen Terminal then

> rvm use ruby-3.1.1

> rvm --default use 3.1.1

Finally,

> sudo gem install cocoapods

Answer (score 1):

For me (MacOS Sonoma 14.0) the solution was:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Then click yes to download.

You might also want to check that you've agreed to the Xcode license.

Thanks to [ArionHardison](https://github.com/rubygems/bundler/issues/3372#issuecomment-232454424) for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

RUN

gem install bundler && 
gem install rake && 
wget -c https://github.com/wurmlab/sequenceserver/archive/1.1.0.beta12.tar.gz  && 
tar xfvz 1.1.0.beta12.tar.gz && 
cd sequenceserver-1.1.0.beta12 && 
npm install -g
bundle install

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

I needed to set `export BUNDLE_BUILD__SASSC=--disable-march-tune-native` to workout around some compiling error in some SASS gem.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to init the lastest version of React Native project, it might happen.
I tried to decrease version of RN `npx react-native@0.69.9 init myProject`.
And after that I faced with error that pods weren't installed.
It tried to `cd ./myProject/ios` and make `bundle exec pod install`
After that it works great.