Does Ruby on rails work on the new Snapdragon X ARM computers?
I'm trying to set up Rails on my Windows 11 computer on a Snapdragon(R) X 12-core X1E80100 computer. When I try to create a new project, the rails new statement fails (output and make file logs below) -
The system points to C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/extensions/x64-mingw-ucrt/3.2.0/psych-5.1.2/mkmf.log, which is looking for yaml.h:
I'm just installing Ruby, restarting, installing the rails gem, using rails new to create my app, and it fails.
Any ideas what/s going wrong? Thank you!
Installing psych 5.1.2 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.


...and later...
An error occurred while installing psych (5.1.2), and Bundler cannot continue.

In Gemfile:

debug was resolved to 1.9.2, which depends on

irb was resolved to 1.14.0, which depends on

rdoc was resolved to 6.7.0, which depends on

psych

run bundle lock --add-platform=x86_64-linux

Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........

Resolving dependencies...

Writing lockfile to C:/Users/TomMo/Code/Journaley/Gemfile.lock

run bundle binstubs bundler
Could not find debug-1.9.2, irb-1.14.0, rdoc-6.7.0, psych-5.1.2 in locally

PATH=".;C:/Ruby32-x64/lib;C:\Ruby32-x64\bin;C:\Ruby32-x64\msys64\ucrt64\bin;C:\Ruby32-x64\msys64\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Ruby32-x64\bin;C:\Users\TomMo\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\TomMo\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\TomMo\.dotnet\tools" x86_64-w64-mingw32-pkg-config --exists yaml-0.1
package configuration for yaml-0.1 is not found
find_header: checking for yaml.h... -------------------- no

PATH=".;C:/Ruby32-x64/lib;C:\Ruby32-x64\bin;C:\Ruby32-x64\msys64\ucrt64\bin;C:\Ruby32-x64\msys64\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Ruby32-x64\bin;C:\Users\TomMo\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\TomMo\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\TomMo\.dotnet\tools" "gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby32-x64/include/ruby-3.2.0/x64-mingw-ucrt -IC:/Ruby32-x64/include/ruby-3.2.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby32-x64/include/ruby-3.2.0 -I. -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1 -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -DYAML_DECLARE_STATIC -O3 -fno-fast-math -fstack-protector-strong conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby32-x64/lib -L. -pipe -s -fstack-protector-strong -Wl,--no-as-needed  -m64   -lx64-ucrt-ruby320  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi -lbcrypt  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
6: {
7:   return !!argv[argc];
8: }
/* end */

PATH=".;C:/Ruby32-x64/lib;C:\Ruby32-x64\bin;C:\Ruby32-x64\msys64\ucrt64\bin;C:\Ruby32-x64\msys64\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Ruby32-x64\bin;C:\Users\TomMo\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\TomMo\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\TomMo\.dotnet\tools" "gcc -IC:/Ruby32-x64/include/ruby-3.2.0/x64-mingw-ucrt -IC:/Ruby32-x64/include/ruby-3.2.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby32-x64/include/ruby-3.2.0 -I. -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1 -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -DYAML_DECLARE_STATIC -O3 -fno-fast-math -fstack-protector-strong -m64  -c conftest.c"
conftest.c:5:10: fatal error: yaml.h: No such file or directory
    5 | #include <yaml.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: #include <yaml.h>
/* end */

--------------------

I searched online for a solution. I tried explicitly installing the psych gem , and that fails as well.

Have you checked this post ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62965073/gemextbuilderror-error-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension-keep-getting  Actually installing Ruby/Rails on Windows is not as straightforward as on Mac or Linux. I remember I used something like https://rubyinstaller.org/ to install all dependencies but to be honest it was not super smooth.

Save yourself a lot of grief and install WSL2 and some flavor of Linux. Do you imagine yourself deploying your apps to Windows server? If the answer is no you're really just setting up a massive footgun for yourself.

thanks for your question.
Qualcomm is aware of the issues that exist with Ruby. Currently. Due to other dependencies, a native version of Ruby is not available nor is there an immediate fix available.
